# How to calculate $P(\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}<1)$

Tags: probability

Consider $X\sim U(0,1) , Y\sim U(0,1)$ be continuous **independents** variables.
I need to calculate $$P(\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}<1)$$.
So far i try to do something like this:
$$P(\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}<1) = P(X^2+Y^2<1) = P(X^2<1 , Y^2<1-X^2) = P(X<1,Y<\sqrt{1-X^2})$$
But i really stuck here. what is the next step? tnx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
P(\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}<1) &= P(X^2+Y^2<1)\\
&=\int_{y=0}^1\int_{x=0}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\frac{1}{1-0}\frac{1}{1-0} dx dy\\
&=\int_0^1\sqrt{1-y^2} dy\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}.
\end{align}

---

To calculate the integral $\displaystyle \int_0^1\sqrt{1-y^2} dy$, use $y=\sin z$:
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\sqrt{1-y^2} dy &= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^2z dz\\
&=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1+\cos 2z}{2} dz\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$X$ and $Y$ fill the square $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ with uniform probability. Thus, the desired answer is $\frac{1}{4}$ the area of the circle with radius $1$. That is, $\frac{1}{4}\pi$.

[image]

Comment: It should be $\frac 14 \pi$.